# When do I use Ampere's Circuital Law?

Tags: magnetic-fields

A steady current I flows along an infinitely long hollow cylindrical conductor of radius R. This cylinder is placed coaxially inside an infinite solenoid of radius 2R. The solenoid has n turns per unit length and carries a steady current I. Consider a point P at a distance r from the common axis. The correct statement(s) is (are):

A)In the region 0 < r < R, the magnetic field is non-zero

B)In the region R < r < 2R, the magnetic field is along the common axis

C)In the region R < r < 2R. the magnetic field is tangential to the circle of radius r, centered on the axis

D)In the region r > 2R, the magnetic field is non-zero

I tried to apply Ampere's  Circuital Law by using a circular loop inside the hollow conductor and used symmetry to obtain that thre is no field inside.So I got only option C) as right.

But, the answer says that there is a  non zero field inside the region of the conductor - the field of the solenoid!

But does the field of the solenoid exist in that region?
Have I used the law rightly? Should I be using Ampere's law here or just superimpose the fields of the conductor and solenoid?

Why I cannot use symmetry to state that magnetic field is tangential to the loop  at all points?

Why does symmetry fail here?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using amperes law you can only conclude that inside the hollow cylinder in the circular loop the line integral of B.dl = 0 (here there is a dot product between B and dl) this generally does not imply that B = 0, here in your question B is non zero and B is perpendicular to dl of the loop so the line integral of B.dl is zero.

Comment: But since the loop is circular , there is a symmetry , so B should be a constant all over the loop. So , B can be taken out of the integral and it comes to be zero. But how do I calculate the field due to cylinder inside itself? Why is  "B is perpendicular to dl"?

Comment: B is constant but it cannot be taken out of the integral as B is a vector with a dot product with B.dl = |B|*Cos($\theta$)*dl but here $\theta$ = pi/2 so B.dl = 0 which does not imply |B| = 0. Field due to hollow cylinder inside the cylinder is zero but B due to solenoid over there is non zero

Comment: Ok , so can we just superimpose the two fields like that? Won't the hollow conductor affect the field of the solenoid?

Comment: Yes we can superimpose electric and magnetic fields